# Transform a data table from column based data to list column headers by their unique table entries

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, flatten, google-query-language, data-transform

googlesheet new user here. Am trying to wrangle to some data in the most efficient way possible. I have done this transformation already via a formula of lookups and if statements but have to believe there is a better way with a query function or similar? any guidance would be greatly appreciated. The image shows the transformation required - would also be grateful if you could suggest how this question could be better worded. Thank you.

[Transformation - from/to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYPKA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:B13&"¤×"&A1:B1&","), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "¤")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: That’s a magic trick (I.e. I can’t explain how you did that…yet…but will pick it apart!). Thank you very much. If you know any good tutorials etc on this - very happy to take recommendations.

Comment: @Swiss23 I would say that the best tutorial is when you take it apart and see what exactly each piece of formula does

Comment: The one element of it that I have searched for info on already is this symbol… ¤ …if you could give me a clue on this one…I will work on the rest…thanks

Comment: Got it - it’s a symbol delimiter for SPLIT which is v unlikely to be in my dataset…